# How to rewrite a find_package based library into one which can be embedded into the parent project directly?

Tags: cmake, webrtc

The library `libwebrtc` from https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/libwebrtc-build/blob/dev/CMakeLists.txt was built to be used with `make; make install` and the project which wants to use the library must later use the `find_package` from CMake.

I, however, want to change `libwebrtc` so it can be added as a git submodule into my current project as a custom library, as, for instance, https://github.com/itay-grudev/SingleApplication which is compiled when I type: cmake ..; make into a static/dynamic library and then linked in my main application. (The Qt library example I references earlier was confusing since this is build outside of my main project and only linked to afterwards - which is not what I want). Sorry for that confusion.

To be able to do that, I think that the `ExternalProject_Add` at https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/libwebrtc-build/blob/a24a5e5947658d43339d4bfd85d3f4c52fc71057/CMakeLists.txt#L100 must be changed into a `add_library` call.

The problem here is that the `include_directories` is used by the main project before the library has been completely built.

## Question

How to rewrite `libwebrtc` to be used as a simple static library with proper build dependencies so that my main project is only compiled/linked after the `libwebrtc` build was finished and custom header files were generated in the `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` of `libwebrtc`.

Or in other words, how to rewrite `libwebrtc` to be used without having to call `make install` for the library and then use `find_package` to use that library.

## The hack (which is working already)

With this hack I am already able to:

- Build the library from my parent project
- Depend on the generated header files which exist only after the `libwebrtc` has been built completely (thus, delay main project building until dependencies are meet)
- Depend on the generated webrtc.a static library for the linker step

I imaging that `make install` will work since `libwebrtc` is statically linked.

```
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} libwebrtcx)
add_subdirectory(third-party/libwebrtcx)
include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/sources/third-party/libwebrtcx/include/webrtc
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/sources/third-party/libwebrtcx/include/webrtc/third_party/libyuv/include/
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/sources/third-party/libwebrtcx/webrtc/src/third_party/abseil-cpp
)

add_library(libwebrtc STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET libwebrtc PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/sources/third-party/libwebrtcx/webrtc/src/out/Release/obj/libwebrtc.a")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} libwebrtc)
```

Note: It requires to rename the **libwebrtc** project to **libwebrtcx** and also the `ExternalProject_Add` at https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/libwebrtc-build/blob/a24a5e5947658d43339d4bfd85d3f4c52fc71057/CMakeLists.txt#L100 must be renamed to **libwebrtcx**.

Note: It also requires to rename all `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` into `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` and `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` to `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`. Details can be found here: [CMake: Using add_subproject with a library using Include ends up in wrong relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61007492/cmake-using-add-subproject-with-a-library-using-include-ends-up-in-wrong-relati)

Comment: If I got your question right, you want to be able to do `ExternalProject_Add` without actually downloading anything (because this external project lives in your source tree as a submodule). Typically this is can be achieved simply by running `add_subdirectory` (potentially with `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` option).

Comment: My goal is to integrate libwebrtc as a sub-project in my application so that each time i rebuild my application it will also rebuild libwebrtc. I want proper dependency management.